# What happens to a question when it becomes a Great Question?

Tags: discussion, questions, badges, upvotes

I have a bulk question, [Setting up maven dependency for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942407/setting-up-maven-dependency-for-sql-server)  for which I just received a Great Question badge for having a score of 100.

What surprised me I got normally one vote per some two weeks or so and now on the day I reached 100 I had 102 votes before I realized I got the badge. I have been waiting this to happen, so I look my profile daily.

Is there some list or advertiser where the Great Questions go after receiving the badge or is the amount of upvotes just a coincidence that happened the same day I got the badge? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Just a coincidence, I think.

Comment: Maybe three numbers below the upvote button attract the sight more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such list for questions, but your badge will appear in the Recent badges list in the right sidebar of the [Badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) page. That might have attracted some extra attention, but I doubt it as the turnover of that page is quite fast.

It's far more likely that the edit on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15923048/4751173), which bumped the question to the front page, drew extra attention to your question.